# How to write C# DataSet object to XML with customized nodes structure?

Tags: c#, xml, dataset, writexml

I have a similar case - I receive a DataSet object  with data tables willed with data (e. g. customers table ...)  from an external module (done by other programmer).

I then save the data set object to an xml using the writeXml method - here is my code

```
public void Save(string myXmlFilePath)
{        
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; 
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None;

    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(myXmlFilePath, settings))
    {
        ExportObject.WriteXml(writer);
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

I get the standard xml file output structure like this:

```
<NewDataSet>
    <Customers>...</Customers>
    <Customers>...</Customers>
<NewDataSet>`
```

However I want the structure like this

```
<Customers>
    <Customer>...</Customer>
    <Customer>...</Customer>
</Customers>`
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Specify the desired names to the dataset and the tables within it.

```
ExportObject.DataSetName = "Customers";
ExportObject.Tables[0].TableName = "Customer";
```

Comment: That's what I also thought, so I did name all the tables in the data set. This did not help

Comment: I understand you - if I had only one table this would work but I have many tables like Customers, Products etc. so just naming the data set as "Customers" will not do the job

Comment: One possible solution that I just found is:

Answer (score 0):

A work around is to let `WriteXml` write however it likes and then do an XSD transform to the format you prefer.